# methods to automatically add columns to mysql table based on other tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, bash

I am trying to find an optimum way to automatically add (and possibly remove) columns in a mysql table based on other tables. Currently I use a script via cron (bash, php etc) to check table A and then update table B. I am wondering if there is a way to do this internally within mysql using mysql scripts/statements automatically based on an update of the table?

**SCHEMA AS EXAMPLE ONLY TO CLARIFY QUESTION**

table A  : this is the table that will be manually updated

```
Name  : cloud_environments
cloud_env_id : id
cloud_env_name : name (ie dev1)
<DATA>
id:1, name:dev_env_1
id:2, name:staging_env_1
id:3, name:production_env_1
```

table B : should be auto updated when a new value is placed in table A, each cloud_env_id should have three fields in table B,

> cloud_env_id
>
> status for environment
>
> version for environment

so the initial table will look like

```
name : cloud_env_details
cloud_env_detail_id : id
cloud_env_detail_name_id1 : dev1    //name:dev_env_1
cloud_env_detail_status_id1 : active    //status of dev_env_1
cloud_env_detail_version_id1 : 0.3.3    //version dev_env_1
cloud_env_detail_name_id2 : sta1    //name:staging_env_1
cloud_env_detail_status_id2 : active    //status of staging_env_1
cloud_env_detail_version_id2 : 0.2.3    //version staging_env_1
cloud_env_detail_name_id3 : prd1    //name:production_env_1
cloud_env_detail_status_id3 : active    //status of production_env_1
cloud_env_detail_version_id3 : 0.1.1    //version production_env_1
```

Now if I add a new environment to table A, such as

> id4, name dev_env_2

I would like to add the additional template columns to table B automatically

```
cloud_env_detail_name_id4 : dev2    //name:dev_env_2
cloud_env_detail_status_id4 : NULL    //status of dev_env_2
cloud_env_detail_version_id4 : NULL    //version dev_env_2
```

Comment: once columns start have numbers the whole db structure is probably wrong

Comment: looks like you should have table with : `id, name, status, version` -- then rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Triggers`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html) are used for what you are talking about. You could use it.

Comment: link only answers are discouraged

Comment: @Harshit, thanks for prompt answer. Looks like the correct solution.